# Python Login method from another module

Tags: python, oop, authentication, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI application and I am trying to configure the login system. I have two modules (two files). In one module the login method checks user entry upon database and this part works successfully. In the other module I am trying to gather the results of self.loggedIn from the intitial module, so the system knows the user is logged in.

```
#Method from file 1
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    def logIn():
        from backend import Database
        db = Database()
        login = db.login((username_text.get(),password2_text.get()))
        if db.loggedIn is True:
            print("yes")

#Method from file 2
class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        self.loggedIn = False

    def login(self, username, password):
        conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
        cur=conn.cursor()
        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM customerDetails WHERE email = ? AND password = ?")
        cur.execute(find_user, [(username), (password)])
        results = cur.fetchall()
```

Error: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: logIn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: This code won't give that error, because your `__init__` is missing some code. Second, the error message says `logIn` expects an argument but the code does not have an argument in it. Finally, nothing in your code ever calls the `logIn` function, or instantiates either of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, you need at least `self` in your `logIn` method:

```
def logIn(self):
```

Comment: Done. Now I have the error:     return self.func(*args)
TypeError: logIn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @Stec if you have new error then create new question on new page. You will have more space to put error and needed code. And it will be more reasdable.

Comment: @Stec you should add `self` in `login(self, username, password):` and you should use instance of Database - `db = Database()` and `login = db.login(...)` and check `if db.loggedIn:` eventually `if db.loggedIn is True:`

Comment: @Hoenie maybe you could add these fixes to your answer.

Comment: I have updated my code. After all adjustments you two said to do, I have: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: logIn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.